# Do we have any example of fundamental forces not working or having errors?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, biology, laws-of-physics

When we read about DNA, we see that the laws of chemistry and biochemistry and biology are rigid. But once in a while these laws fail to act (correct me if I'm wrong) and that is the source of what we know as mutation.

For example, during [DNA replication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_replication) we read:

> In general, DNA polymerases are highly accurate, with an intrinsic error rate of less than one mistake for every $10^7$ nucleotides added. In addition, some DNA polymerases also have proofreading ability; they can remove nucleotides from the end of a growing strand in order to correct mismatched bases. Finally, post-replication mismatch repair mechanisms monitor the DNA for errors, being capable of distinguishing mismatches in the newly synthesized DNA strand from the original strand sequence. Together, these three discrimination steps enable replication fidelity of less than one mistake for every $10^9$ nucleotides added.

I wonder if this can also be said for physical laws.

For example, in a simple Newtonian gravity, every two objects that have mass apply attractional forces on each other **constantly**.

Can we say that once in each $N$th seconds, gravity stops acting and then comes back into action?

In other words, how are we sure that physical laws and forces are acting $100\%$ of the time and not $99.999999999999\%$ for example?

Comment: Closed? Typical discouraging SE move, look if everyone here is supposed to ask expert questions then go ahead deleted this post and block this user, and if not, well this was a perfectly fine question, not confusing at all, shows genuine curiosity that users like me totally understand AND ask in everyday lives. Sorry that this question didnt contain equations to show the intellect of the poster so the community could drool over and up vote it endlessly. Idiots. Doubt me? Go ask OP, you definitely have discouraged and disappointed him for sure. + to Vadim for answering though!

Comment: I actually agree that this question should be reopened, or a duplicate linked to if this has already been answered on the site. Actually, establishing bounds on how much fundamental constants might drift over time is actually an important subfield of metrological physics.

Comment: Yeah, I'm the OP of this question, and many times I felt discouraged and disappointed by this behavior of SE. But I can't do anything about it. Thus I just have to suffer in my loneliness, as this is just another example of tyranny and cruelty.

Comment: hey Saeed, i have felt the same for years, but lets try to ignore that, have you read Vadim's answer, its excellent and to the point.

Answer (score 6):

You are mistaken about the equivalence between physical and biological law. Particularly, DNA copying by a polymeraze is not a law at all, but a physical and chemical process, which, like any process is prone to noise.

I will let others to give more specific examples about the fundamental forces, which are not my field of expertise. However, whenever the physics laws are found to give incorrect predictions, it is a signal that we need to develop a better theory: this how newtonian mechanics gave rise to relativity at high speeds and quantum mechanics at small scales. Note also, that *it is not the laws of physics themselves that mulfunction, but our knowledge of them is incomplete.*

Comment: Put another way: if we restrict ourselves to using physical equations and notions only developed before X year (e.g. 1900), *of course* they will yield incorrect predictions some percentage of the time. It was observing these cases that led us to improving the equations in the first place. This is quite different than saying the underlying physical "laws" of the universe change or just blip out for a nanosecond. If the universe is mathematically consistent, those effects can be understood (we hope, by human-level intellect) and modeled, leading to new physical "laws."

Comment: From what I understood in particle physics, forces are also proccesses. For example, an electron smashing into the nucleous, emitting -W boson, becoming neutrino, then that -W boson hitting a proton and turning it into neutron. Is it not a process?

Comment: @SaeedNeamati This is an interesting way to see it. I think your question has many interesting aspects, despite appearing a bit naïve, and I fully expected the people with particle physics background to contribute. It is a pity that it is closed. Perhaps, you could ask a more precise question, drawing on the analogy between DNA copying and particle exchange in the fundamental forces.